# Android ExpandableListView GroupIndicator gravity

Tags: android, expandablelistview, gravity

How to change default `GroupIndicator` gravity of Android `ExpandableListView`?

Answer (score 1):

Set android:groupIndicator="@null" in "expandablelist"

Add ImageView in "groupview" xml

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ImageView mGroupIndicator=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mGroupimage);
     if(isExpanded){
         mGroupIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.expanded);
     }else{
         mGroupIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.collapsed);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the default one.. but if you are implementing custom Adapter .. you can put a checkBox with group indicator background and position it where ever you want..